# Insert number in Meteor Collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I wanted to insert a variable to my Meteor Collection as a number. However when I checked in the client console and mini mongodb console they are saved as string.

Here's my code :

```
Gifts.insert({
    category : t.find('#selectCat').value,
    amount : parseFloat(inputAmount).toFixed(2),
    desc : description,
    createdAt : new Date(),
    createdBy : Meteor.user().username
});
```

I also tried `amount : Number(inputAmount).toFixed(2)`, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solve my problem.

I insert the amount as number by `Number(inputAmount)` :

```
Gifts.insert({
    category : t.find('#selectCat').value,
    amount : Number(inputAmount),
    desc : description,
    createdAt : new Date(),
    createdBy : Meteor.user().username,
});
```

Then, I created a helper to format the amount when rendered in html :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("formatAmount", function(str) {
    return str.toFixed(2);
});
```

During render I do it this way: `{{formatAmount amount}}`

Answer (score 0):

The `toFixed` method converts number to a formatted string. Just remove it so that your variable stays as a number.

Comment: I was trying to get the value from the input text field and format them to have two decimal places and assigned to my  'var inputAmount'. After the formatting I then insert to the Collection. Is there any way to format the 'inputAmount'?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
amount : parseFloat(inputAmount).toFixed(2)
```

to

```
amount : parseFloat(inputAmount).round(2)
```

to make the return value still a number with 2 decimal places.

For the second one

```
amount : Number(inputAmount);
```

probably you need to do:

```
amount : new Number(inputAmount);
```

Comment: `parseFloat(inputAmount).round(2)` will have an `undefined is not a function`.